# How to use Arial Regular font? like what is regular? is it a font-weight?

Tags: css, fonts, frontend

In an Assignment, it is given that I have to use Font - Arial, Regular! what is regular in it?

Answer (score 1):

When a font is designed for general use it is usually published in several forms known as a family, regular, italic, bold, condensed, light and so on, some in combination as well such as "bold italic".
*regular* is the version intended for everyday use when you do not need typographical embellishments. The  Arial family, being a popular font has, 20 main variants plus several further versions such as "rounded". For more detail on Arial read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial).

Comment: So, This regular is  font weight?

Comment: Yes, but also says that it is not italic for example.

Comment: Thank You :) , so I have to use it like `font-family: Arial; font-weight: regular;`

Comment: That depends on the software you are using. If, for example, you are writing your assignment using Word then on the "Home" tab you can select the font used in a drop down menu. It will just appear as _**Arial**_, _regular_ is assumed if you don't select anything else If it is some other software then you will have to look up the specific method of applying a font.

Comment: NO, Not Word I am have assignment in HTML and CSS.

Comment: Take a look at [https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp] for more information about fonts in CSS than you will ever need.